# PHP cURL proxy WITH header?

Tags: php, image, curl, proxy, header

I'm making a PHP image proxy script.  I need it to not only echo the contents of the image it requests, but also identically reproduce the header of the image request.

I've seen one, and the other, but not both together... and these cURL option things confuse me.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not sure what is you want.

This is the example to get from a image url, echo header and save image to a file.

But, if you want a proxy, you should use web server (Nginx, Apache, etc), PHP is no need

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://img3.cache.netease.com/www/logo/logo_png.png");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.163.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

list($header, $image) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $return, 2);

echo $header;

file_put_contents("/tmp/logo.png", $image);
```

Comment: Had to change a lot of the code, but it had exactly what I needed to figure it out myself.  Thanks so much!  You saved me :D

Comment: Please for the love of god explain what you had to do this is from google for PHP CURL proxy image and you dont say why part of it worked for you

Answer (score -1):

You can get all the headers (not as raw text) with `getallheaders()`

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Then string them back together:

```
$headers = "";
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    $headers = "$name: $value\r\n";
}
$headers .= "\r\n"; // Double newline to signal end of headers (HTTP spec)
```

Then I think the best way is to use a socket connection, rather than CURL like so:

```
$response = '';
$fp = fsockopen('example.org', 80);
fputs($fp, $headers);
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $response .= fgets($fp, 128);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Note that you may need to modify the host/request headers (because this is an identical copy, as you asked), and you may need to implement redirect following.

Comment: He's asking for the headers from the request he's proxy'ing to a backend. e.g. the proxy request.  getallheaders will give the request headers from the caller, not those concerning the call to the backend. above all getallheaders() is also not supported on all platforms like noteworthy php-cgi (only apache and some) before version 5.4.0, so if you are on nginx you'll need to do some tricks.